# "Error: Program type already present: com.google.zxing.aztec.detector.Detector"

Tags: java, android-studio, qr-code, zxing

I'm a newbie programmer working on a research project with Android Studio. My research involves the scanning and generating of QR codes which I used Zxing for. I've just finished the code in generating the QR code but then when I ran it this appeared

"Error: Program type already present: com.google.zxing.aztec.detector.Detector"

The program had no errors only minor warnings.

Here's my build gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "csar.app.com.cnshsstudentactivityrecorder"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation files('libs/core-3.2.1.jar')
}
```

Comment: post your build gradle